# Can't find data referred to in an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've inherited a spreadsheet with no instructions.

There is a formula in one of the cells:

```
=IFERROR(ROUND((SUM('RawData'!C:C)/K21)*24*60*60,0),0)
```

There are no hidden tabs - so I'm guessing 'RawData' is a named reference of some sort.

Is there any way for me to find out where the data is referred to in 'RawData'?

Thanks for any help, Mark

Comment: RawData looks like the name of a sheet, have you checked every sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worksheet `RawData` will be a [`Very Hidden`](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/making_a_spreadsheet_very_hidden.html) sheet.  That means it will not show up in the the normal hide/unhide dialog in Excel.

You will need to use the VBE(Alt-F11) Then Ctr-r if the project Exploreer is not already visible.

Find the sheet in the list click it and change the hidden aspect in the properties of that sheet.

[image]

Comment: alt+f11 then ctrl+R to show the Project Explorer. Alternately, View, Project Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Running the following VBA will also unhide all sheets:

```
For Each Sht In Application.Worksheets
    Sht.Visible = True
Next Sht
```